Given a cumulative distribution function can you find the random variable associated with it?
Without sampling or using the uniform distribution can you prove that either a random variable is associated with a given CDF or not?

Can you give a lot more details in order to clarify what your question is? For example, you might be asking: (a) for a given function $F$, how to determine whether $F$ is the c.d.f. of some random variable $X$ on some probability space? (b) for a given probability space and a given $F$, how to determine whether there is a random variable on that space with the c.d.f $F$? (c) something else.... And what does "without sampling" mean? One doesn't normally "sample" in order to "prove" something.
